# How to set the size of a vector member of a struct upon intialization?

Tags: c++, object, vector, struct

I would like to set the size of a member vector when I construct a `struct`. The reason for this is that I have found that `resize()` can be very slow.

Here is some minimal code trying to do what I want, but broken.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Struct_w_Vector {
    ~Struct_w_Vector() {} // destructor

    int n;
    vector<double> h(n, 0.0);

    Struct_w_Vector(int n) : n(n) {
        // create vector h of size n filled with 0.0 now because resize() takes much more time
    } // constructor
};

int main() {
    vector<double> h(10, 0.0);  // what I would like to make happen inside of the struct
    Struct_w_Vector v(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to set the size of the `vector` of `double`s named `h` to be of `n` size filled with all 0's upon construction (without using resize)?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will achieve what you need:

```
Struct_w_Vector(int n) : n(n), h(n) {}
```

This one is close, but the use of parentheses isn't allowed in standard C++, and furthermore, `n` isn't initialized at that point:

```
vector<double> h(n, 0.0);
```

So better drop it.

Note that you probably don't need to store `n`, because you can always get the vector's size with `h.size()`. You don't need to declare a destructor either. That leaves you with

```
struct Struct_w_Vector {
    vector<double> h;
    Struct_w_Vector(int n) : h(n) {}
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not make "h" a pointer and initialize it with a new vector in the constructor?

```
struct Struct_w_Vector {
    ~Struct_w_Vector() {
        delete h;
    } // destructor

    int n;
    vector<double> *h;

    Struct_w_Vector(int n) : n(n) {
        h = new vector<double>(n, 0.0);
    } // constructor
};
```

Comment: Bjarne says it’s typically not a good idea to use new. (I did not downvote.) Is this the only option?

Comment: 1. `new` is not needed in this case, just initialize `h` in the struct constructor's *member initialization list* instead (see [juanchopanza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63419957/65863)). 2. by using `new`, but omitting copy/move constructor(s) and copy/move assignment operator(s) to manage the pointer *correctly*, this struct is violating the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which can lead to all kinds of problems.